# How to fix CVE-2016-5195 on ubuntu-server 14.04.2 LTS

Tags: server

There is some problem with the bug CVE-2016-5195
I fixed it following [this guide](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/dirtycow-linux-cve-2016-5195-kernel-local-privilege-escalation-vulnerability-fix/)
and used the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After that,I rebooted the server, and the version of the system is Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

Then, I followed [this guide](https://www.redpacketsecurity.com/testing-dirty-cow-cve-2016-5195/) to test the bug, but found the bug still exists.

How do I mitigate this?

Here is the output about kernel version:

```
root@ubuntu:~# uname -r
3.16.0-30-generic
```

Comment: Which kernel are you using? Could you [edit] your question to include the output of `uname -r`, please?

Comment: So sorry,I forgot that.Here is the output:root@ubuntu:~# uname -r
3.16.0-30-generic

Comment: 3.16 kernels are no longer supported in Ubuntu; please uninstall them. The supported version in 14.04 are 3.13 and 4.4.

Answer (score 4):

As I suspected and the comments confirm, you're using an old "HWE" update which hasn't been supported for a LONG time. You need to upgrade.

In case you're not sure what I'm rambling on about, the long term support (LTS) releases of Ubuntu have update packs which add new hardware support by bundling together the kernel and X stack of newer Ubuntu releases.

In this case Linux 3.16 was in Utopic (14.10). it was bundled with 14.04.2. It was was supported for as long as the main release of Utopic, which means it's been end-of-life since July 2015. Erk.

You have a few options:

1. Upgrade to [the latest HWE for 14.04, 14.04.5](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes#LTS_Hardware_Enablement_Stack), based on 16.04 Xenial and supported until April 2019. That's using a much newer kernel so *may* not work on your hardware. Installing it is fairly simple:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial
   ```
2. You could also downgrade to the kernel that shipped with 14.04.1. This is based on the initial release of 14.04 and is supported to April 2019 too. Because it's older it might also not support your hardware. Testing is everything ;)
3. If #1 works, you might also want to consdier upgrading to 16.04 proper. This is the next LTS after 14.04 and is supported to 2020. But it will also update other stuff. The biggest change for server users is the init system has changed from upstart to systemd. Takes some getting used to if you have custom startup scripts.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that a point release is tied to a specific kernel version. This is not correct, and in particular "downgrading to 14.04.1" is not possible. OP is, and will stay, on 14.04.5, the problem is the residual Utopic kernel, which must be uninstalled manually and replaced with a supported one (either the 3.13 from Trusty or the 4.4 from Xenial).

Comment: I think that really depends on your interpretation. The number that gets scrawled into `/etc/lsb-release` doesn't have much to do with what is part of that point release. In the context of kernel versions, I think talking about point releases is pretty clear but if you want to , imagine I'm saying "the version of the kernel that ships with [point release]". (I've edited since).